# Removing slivers from IPolygon using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, polygon, slivers

ArcGIS Desktop Basic 10.1 with Spatial Analyst and 3D Analyst

I have multiple neighboring polygons which I unionize. On occasion the result has slivers where the multiple polygons meet. I have been searching on the simplest way to get rid of these slivers but it seems like all tools work on features or feature classes. The result is a IPolygon element which I am drawing to the screen so don’t use the IFeature or IFeatureClass objects.

The before and after looks like this:

[image]

The end result should be one complete polygon with no slivers. The dimensions of the polygons are in 2 to 3 miles and the slivers are very tiny. I've zoomed in very close so estimate the slivers to be about ~5FT which is negligible for my purposes.

To unionize I have tried:

```
ITopologicalOperator4.Simplify seems only ensures the topology is correct 
Integrate_management and RepairGeometry_management require feature classes 
Eliminate requires Desktop Advanced which I don't have
```

My goal is to unionize the collection of IPolygon objects with no slivers?

Comment: Slivers only make sense in the context of multiple neighboring polygons (as in a topology). There is no interface to identify a sliver in the context of a singleton shape.

Comment: I added details to the question but I do have multiple polygons which I then unionize. the resultant polygon is the one with slivers.

Comment: So you have a number of interior rings ("holes")? Have you tried extracting only the exterior? Or calculating a convex hull?  Or subtracting the shape from the envelope, then unioning the interal parts to fill hole? Doing new development on Retired software may introduce complications.

Comment: Can you get rid of the slivers during the Union process by adjusting the  cluster tolerance?

Comment: vince the polygons are all simple polygons with no holes. dan the union function I am using is with the TopoOperator and has no tolerance input.

Comment: You'll need to make up your mind. Either you have a polygon with no holes or you have slivers, but you can't have both. Please [Edit] the question to contain the correct parts of the conflicting information you have provided in comments, along with some graphics that explain what you have and what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: I have both. I think we are using different definitions. My individual polygons are simple with no holes inside them. When I unionize them I get these tiny slivers at the edge which may not be a hole but just two more edges that are really close (probably within 5 feet or so). But the sliver is so small I cannot tell. I will add a graphic to the op.

Comment: Not sure why the question was put on hold. I added a graphic and made the explanation clearer.

Comment: What your'e looking for is an interior angle that is *very* sharp, you can use IConstructAngle http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000000qs000000 to see if a series of 3 points forms a very sharp angle and remove from the collection (IPointCollection) but be sure to keep the first point to test if the next is also very sharp.. sorry I don't have time today to give a code example. When checking a ring be sure to check if *at least 3* points form a significant triangle or you might need to remove the whole part.

Comment: That's a good idea. The boundaries are very densified so it may take a while to process. Let me give that a shot.